# mongodb connection timed out error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have used mongodb database and node.js v12.0.10 for connecting and updating mongodb collection.
connection code is the following:

```
 async.parallel({
        RE5: function (cb) {
            MongoClient.connect(config.riskEngineDB, function (err, r5DB) {
                cb(err, r5DB);
            })
        },
        MDB: function (cb) {
            MongoClient.connect(config.monitoringDB, function (err, mDB) {
                cb(err, mDB);
            })
        }
    },
    function (err, DBs) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected correctly to Dbs");
        // ..doing updates..

 })
```

after some time running, script printed the following error:

```
  { [MongoError: connection 39 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 39 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out' }
```

For your information, I used different options of connections of mongodb but it didn't make sense.

Comment: For anyone looking to set the initial database connection timeout, you can do so via `serverSelectionTimeoutMS`. Currently this option is not documented here https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

Answer (score 22):

I wanted to provide this answer as it came up in a mongodb exam question for the free online mongodb university. It's thorough and provides documentation.

I have figured it out and will clean up some confusion mainly caused by a lack of explanation in the lessons.  I am not being critical but further explanation is required to properly answer this question.

First, when connecting to mongodb through an application you will be using a driver.  This driver has barriors it must pass through in order to do anything with the mongodb server.  When you understand this barrior concept you will then understand this question.

Every connection that is ultimately made a list of things have to occur in order to pass throuh the barriers and ultimately conduct a write or read operaton.

**Visually you can think of it like this:**

> IO / write request occurs ==> || **1st** barrier --> (server selection - (err ->  [`serverSelectionTimeoutMS`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.serverSelectionTimeoutMS) ) ) ==>  || **2nd** barrier --> connection to server - (err -> ['connectionTimeoutMS'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#urioption.connectTimeoutMS)) ==> || **3rd** barrier --> socket connection -  (err -> ['socketTimeoutMS'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#urioption.socketTimeoutMS)) ==****Write Concern Options Barriers**==> || **4th** barrier --> ['write concern specification { w: <value>, j: <boolean>, wtimeout: <number> }'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#write-concern) ==> || **5th** barrier --> a successful write / read operation

*****Note**: Anywhere along this pipeline a falure occurs based on your logic a successful write / read operation may not occur.

We can think of barriers 1 - 3 as network barriers of connectivity.  If the network is down or having issues these are the problems one would notice through timeouts and exception handling of those timeouts. What one has to understand is that you can't perform a write operation with write concerns if you can't connect to the server in the first place.  The lesson could have illustrated these points.

The first set of barriers to a write or read operation are to have an established connection to the server... This is illustrated above by barries 1 - 3.

Then, after you have a server connection via a cluster and or replica set of clusters then you can define write concerns.

After we have an established connection a write may not happen for reasons other than network connectivity.  These can be collisions of data or an extreme allotment of writes due to DDOS or hacking or in general not enough server space for the data be written to the server.  Point is, something else can cause a reaction to the write concern and hence the control through options to handle write concern errors.

I hope this helps because it made me understand the question and the right answer accordingly.  Mostly, we weren't really taugh this so I hope this helps others learn and understand this feedback loop.

Here are some articles I read to help me get to this answer / conclusion.  If someone has a better or improvement on my explanation please feel free to provide feedback.

https://scalegrid.io/blog/understanding-mongodb-client-timeout-options/

https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-write-concern-3-must-know-caveats/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-selection-next-generation-mongodb-drivers

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I have an optional MongoDB service and if the server is not up, the system should continue as quickly as possible, but it was taking 30 seconds. Until I finally got to this answer: The value that I needed to set was  serverSelectionTimeoutMS and now if the server is not running, it exits quickly

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar experience, due to a query which took too much time to reply

you have 2 configurable timeouts in node mongo driver:

`connectTimeoutMS` and `socketTimeoutMS`, both defaulting to 30sec ( http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/ )

if your query takes longer than 30sec to send its first result, it'll end with a connection timed out error.

if your query takes more than 30sec between two results, it'll probably end with that connection closing due to pool shrinking.

You may want to increase timeouts, or make sure your query is fast enough ( create an index for example). I advise to speed up query, since increasing timeouts may have performances downsides.

Comment: Is it possible to have some information about which queries were taking too long? In my logs, I only have the error saying the connection timeout but I can't find which one it is. Thank you!

Comment: I'm simply handling the error client side and logging the query here.

Comment: Ohh okay! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

"endpoint request timed out" error might also arise due to IP issue.
Just go to mongodb atlas admin panel. In Security tab > Network Access > update IP address as 0.0.0.0/0
[image]