# Mongodb always timeout on first time connect

Tags: c#, mongodb

I had setup a Mongodb database and I am able to connect and query it with Robo 3T without any problem.

When I connect with my C# program, it always throw timeout error on "first" connect.

However there is no problem when if I run the query again without restarting the application.

Environment:

MongoDB 4.2 + MongoDB Driver 2.11

I tried MongoDb 4.4 but it's the same result.

C#:

```
var credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("Mydb", "WebUser", "******");

var client = new MongoClient(
    new MongoClientSettings
    {
        Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
        Credential = credential,
        UseTls = false,
        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct
    });

var database = client.GetDatabase("Mydb");
var collection = db.GetCollection<UserModel>("User");
var documents = collection.Find(_ => true).ToList(); // Timeout on first time connects. Success starting from second time
```

Mongodb Log:

```
NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53288 #54 (1 connection now open)
NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53289 #55 (2 connections now open)
NETWORK  [conn55] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53289 conn55: { driver: { name: "mongo-csharp-driver", version: "2.11.0.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362", architecture: "x86_32", version: "10.0.18362" }, platform: ".NET Framework 4.8.4200.0" }
NETWORK  [conn54] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53288 conn54: { driver: { name: "mongo-csharp-driver", version: "2.11.0.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362", architecture: "x86_32", version: "10.0.18362" }, platform: ".NET Framework 4.8.4200.0" }
```

**EDIT**:

Error message thrown:

```
{"A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }.
Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : \"1\", ConnectionMode : \"Direct\", Type : \"Unknown\", State : \"Disconnected\", Servers : [{ ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/localhost:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/localhost:27017\", ReasonChanged: \"ServerInitialDescription\", State: \"Disconnected\", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: \"Unknown\", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: null, LastUpdateTimestamp: \"2020-08-19T15:59:54.5854245Z\" }] }."}
```

p.s. There is only one collection "Users" and one testing document only.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55030309/2590375) helps you finding the source of your timeout.

Comment: Add complete error message to question.