# Connecting to MongoDB / Atlas from pyspark (DataProc) is getting Error

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Getting the Below error when trying to connect to mongodb via PySpark(Google DATAPROC), its happening both locally and in Dataproc in GCP.  We’re getting the below errors:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.load.
> : com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
> waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,
> servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
> exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
> socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> (Connection refused)}}]
>
> org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Exception in monitor thread while
> connecting to server localhost:27017
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

I’ve been using the below command to submit jobs to dataproc. But we’re not sure where the problem is.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://initmatch/dataproc/files/mongo_spark.py 
--cluster=custom-cluster-no-address --region=us-west1 --jars=gs://initmatch/dataproc/jars/mongo-spark-connector-10.0.5.jar,
gs://initmatch/dataproc/jars/mongodb-driver-core-4.8.1.jar,
gs://initmatch/dataproc/jars/mongodb-driver-sync-4.8.1.jar
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb connection timed out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216639/mongodb-connection-timed-out-error)

Comment: @ray I am trying to connect mongoDb from PySpark Dataproc job But getting the above error . Is this anything we need to do with VPC in Google cloud , Like creating VPC on MongoDb and DataProc to connect.

Comment: Hi @Saranya, can you check your VPC,network partitioning and security setting?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I have not created any VPC for this , Should i need to create VPC for this to connect mongo DB with Dataproc job ? If yes please help me with the steps

Comment: Hi @Saranya, can you clarify whether you have created your Dataproc cluster on GKE or Compute Engine?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar - It is created in Compute Engine only . Attached the screenshots above for your reference. 

Thank you so much for your quick response and doing the needful .. Really Appreciated

Comment: Hi @Saranya, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thank you so much for the suggestion will raise a issue .

Comment: Hello @Saranya - were you able to get a fix for this issue ?